# Checking If Attribute Exists In Any Of Html Tags Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to check out if any html tags have `<style>` attribute like `<a style = ..>` or `<h1 style = ...>` or `<div style = ..>` etc.
I used below code but it could not be run:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(web_driver_address, options=op)
driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("[@style]")
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is missing element tag name.
In your case it can be any tag name, but it still should be there as a part of syntax, so you should use `*` like `any` there.
Also, you are missing the `//` that means the element can be anywhere on the page.
So the correct XPath expression will be something like this:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@style]")
```

Don't forget to add some wait / delay to let page load all the elements before you get them

Answer (score 1):

`xpath` needs tag to be valid. If you don't want a specific tag use `*`

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@style]")
```

Or with `css_selector`

```
find_elements_by_css_selector("[style]")
```